# rake setup github pages

Tags: git, github, blogs, octopress

I am having trouble when I setup `github` pages with `octopress`.
Thanks for your help!

**Exception**

```
$ rake setup_github_pages

rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
D:/octopress/Rakefile:322:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => setup_github_pages
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
## Set the codepage to 65001 for Windows machines
Enter the read/write url for your repository
(For example, 'git@github.com:your_username/your_username.github.io.git)
       or 'https://github.com/your_username/your_username.github.io')
Repository url:
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add your repo on the last line, ignore the errors above.

Once you set it up use the `rake deploy` to upload it to your github account.
You are problem on windows and this is why you get the error.

Here is how to fix it on windows:

https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1835

[image]